# convert NSString from char array contains chinese character

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, jailbreak

I'm use openssl extract code sign from p12 file, and got it. but it not a readable string object. 
for example, my code sign is :""iPhone Developer: 振 王", and the function returns "iPhone Developer: \xE6\x8C\xAF \xE7\x8E\x8B"

here's the code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSString *p1 = @"/Users/william/Desktop/root.p12";
    NSString *s = [self getCodesignFromP12Path:p1 andPassword:@"1"];

    // It's output 'iPhone Developer: \xE6\x8C\xAF \xE7\x8E\x8B (7V3KMVKNR4)'
    NSLog(@"%@", s);
}

- (NSString *)getCodesignFromP12Path:(NSString *)p12Path andPassword:(NSString *)pwd
{
    NSString *string = nil;
    NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"openssl pkcs12 -in %@ -nodes -passin pass:%@ | openssl x509 -noout -subject  | awk -F'[=/]' '{print $6}'", p12Path, pwd];

    FILE*pipein_fp;
    char readbuf[80] = {0};

    if((pipein_fp=popen([command cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],"r"))==NULL)
    {
        perror("popen");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(readbuf,80,pipein_fp))
    {
        string = [NSString stringWithCString:readbuf encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    pclose(pipein_fp);
    return string;
}
```

how can i get the correct chinese character value ?

Comment: Can you print readbuf in while loop?

Comment: Printing description of readbuf:
(char [80]) readbuf = "iPhone Developer: \xE6\x8C\xAF \xE7\x8E\x8B (7V3KMVKNR4)\n"

Comment: @WilliamSterling have you tried to use `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:readbuf]` ?

Comment: that's really strange,     `char *readBuf = "iPhone Developer: \xE6\x8C\xAF \xE7\x8E\x8B";
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:readBuf
                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);`   outputs iPhone Developer: 振 王

Comment: @l0gg3r Yes, but unfortunately it can not too.

Comment: @l0gg3r  I've paste your code and test it, works fine. I think your way (which init a string with hard code) transferred meaning the \x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got the code sign by this solution, but I don't know what cause it if use openssl. here's the [github demo](https://github.com/gslqy/DumpIdentifier).

```
const NSString * kCertificationPassword = @"1";

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSString *ret = nil;
    NSString *cerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"root" ofType:@"p12"];

    // Dump identifier with openssl
    NSString *identifierWithSSL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"openssl pkcs12 -in %@ -nodes -passin pass:%@ | openssl x509 -noout -subject  | awk -F'[=/]' '{print $6}'", cerPath, kCertificationPassword];
    [self shellCMD:identifierWithSSL result:&ret];
    // Output: iPhone Developer: \xE6\x8C\xAF \xE7\x8E\x8B (7V3KMVKNR4)
    NSLog(@"%@", ret);

    // Import certification to keychain.
    NSString *importComand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"security import %@ -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain -P %@ -T /usr/bin/codesign",cerPath, kCertificationPassword];
    [self shellCMD:importComand result:nil];

    // Dump identifier with security.
    NSString *identifierWithSecurity = @"security find-identity -p codesigning | grep 7V3KMVKNR4 | awk -F'[\"\"]' '{print $2}'";
    [self shellCMD:identifierWithSecurity result:&ret];
    // Output: iPhone Developer: 振 王 (7V3KMVKNR4)
    NSLog(@"%@", ret);
}

- (void)shellCMD:(NSString*)cmd result:(NSString**)aResult
{
    FILE*pipein_fp;
    char readbuf[80] = {0};

    if((pipein_fp=popen([cmd cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],"r"))==NULL)
    {
        perror("popen");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(readbuf,80,pipein_fp))
    {
        if ( aResult )
        {
            *aResult = [NSString stringWithCString:readbuf encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        }
    }

    pclose(pipein_fp);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely confusing the output of NSLog with the contents of the string.

NSLog will not print Chinese characters. iOS functions like setting a button title, or the contents to a text will work fine.

Comment: thank you gnasher, but according to my experience, NSLog print Chinese works well. maybe it depends location.